# Git: How to undo git reset --soft HEAD and git push origin +main --force

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and have some difficulties. I have followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/lVpLoUecZYY) on how to delete commits which involves the commands `git reset --soft HEAD~2` and `git push origin +main --force`. However, the outcome was terribly different. It had reverted to not the previous 2 commits but the commit from 3 days ago and I don't know why. I have made many commits and pushes before the reset but their history are now gone on GitHub. Is there a way to get back the commit history and if so, what are the commands?

Edit: I found out about `git reflog` but only have one commit hash. However I have another cloned version of the repository before the reset and have some of the previous commits hashed.

Comment: Let's say you manage to undo the push to Github so that it has the original commit at the `main` branch. Do you then know how to get the undone branch to your cloned repositories without disrupting local work? (If your answer is *yes*, the solution to the posted problem is quite simple provided you have a repository somewhere that has the commit that you want to see on Github.)

Comment: @j6t Fortunately I have deployed the project on Vercel (it's still working) and can still view the repository before the reset but with the warning `This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.`. However, how to get undone branch to the repository and recover the history, I do not know.

Comment: @j6t I actually have another cloned repository before the commit and when I `git reflog`, I can see the commits that were wiped from the reset and push --force. Since I plan to recover the history, I just thought of `git checkout <commit>` all of them leading up to the commit before the reset to push and restore each one. Do you think this is fine?

Comment: Yes, I think it is fine. After doing that, you can just `git push <githuburl> -f HEAD:main`. (`<githuburl>` is probably just `origin`, or it is the `https` URL of your repository.)

Comment: @j6t It succeeded in one push. Everything went back to the way it was before the reset. Maybe something for me to remember before doing another reset push is to keep a clone backup. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: As a sidenote, `--force` and the `+` sign (preceding the ref) are doing the same thing. No need to use both.